# Invalid characters with fromJSON function

Tags: json, r, jsonlite, rjsonio

I am trying to import json file into R. For the purpose I am using packages such as `rjson`, `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO`, etc. I have tried different things as shown below but I got errors with all of them.

```
mydata <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("result_prod_14-15_08_17.json"), collapse=""))
```

The error I got is:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                         {  "_id" : ObjectId("59920f495401ac79452a0
                 (right here) ------^
```

Using 'RJSONIO' package:

```
md <- stream_in(file("result_prod_14-15_08_17.json"))
```

produces the following error:

```
opening fileconnectionoldClass input connection.
Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {
                     (right here) ------^
closing fileconnectionoldClass input connection.
```

It must be something straightforward but since I am new to R I struggle to figure it out.

Comment: The simple answer is that it's not valid JSON. How was the file generated; an export from a database?

Comment: Yes it is actually an export from MongoDB database

Comment: Now that I am thinking brace enclosed {..} items must be part of a larger comma-separated collection which is not the case with my data but if that's the issue I am not sure how I can solve it.

Comment: you can use `library(mongolite)` to query mongodb directly from `R`